# For which values ​of $\alpha$ does this limit equal -2/$\infty$/0

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having trouble with this question. It asks for which values ​​of $\alpha$ does this limit equal -2/$\infty$/0. I imagine that the limit is -2 when the degree of the numerator and the denominator are the same, 0 when that of the denominator is higher and $\infty$ when that of the numerator is higher. I don't understand how to reorder the terms efficiently and how to compare the degree of numerator and denominator.
[image]

I've tried using Taylor but just ended up making a big mess
[image]

Thanks to anyone who decides to help me ☺

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. Moreover I can't copy the Mathjax notation from the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x^4(\cos(x^{-2})-1)=-\frac{1}{2}
$$
see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits#Trigonometric_functions)

and
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \log\left(\frac{2}{x^2}+1\right) \frac{x^2}{2}=1
$$
see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits#Natural_logarithms)

You can rewrite the limit as
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(x-(1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)x^\alpha \frac{x^4}{x^4(\cos(x^{-2})-1)} \log\left(1+\frac{2}{x^2} \right)\frac{x^2}{2}\frac{2}{x^2} =
$$
$$
=-4\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(x-(1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)x^{\alpha+2}
$$
By calculating the Taylor series of the term in the parenthesys you obtain :
$$
-4\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(x-(1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)x^{\alpha+2}=2\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\alpha+1}
$$
i.e. the limit is equal to $2$ when $\alpha={-1}$, $0$ for $\alpha<-1$ and $\infty$ otherwise